# How to use async - await in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new in async programming. and i am working on project where i have to use async await method pattern. For that I have created a method in my repository project

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<InventoryProductMaster>> GetInventoryProducts(long OrganizationMasterID)
    {
        return await _msbmInventoryDbContext.Set<InventoryProductMaster>().Where(a => a.OrganizationMasterID == OrganizationMasterID);
    }
```

And i want to use the result of this function into my controller methods.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
    {
        long organizationMasterID = Convert.ToInt64(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInOrganizationMasterID"]);
        var _materialTypeEntity = await _inventoryUnitOfWork.InventoryProductMasters.GetInventoryProducts(organizationMasterID).ToListAsync();
        return View();
    }
```

**Showing me error message**: 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just `await` any method, that's not how it works. You need to go back to basics and learn how this works.

Comment: Most async BCL methods have ___Async in the method name suffi. The method you are calling in the repo doesn't because it's not async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<InventoryProductMaster>> GetInventoryProducts(long OrganizationMasterID)
{
   return await _msbmInventoryDbContext.Set<InventoryProductMaster>().Where(a => a.OrganizationMasterID == OrganizationMasterID).ToListAsync();
}
```

You will have to use this method and call can happen like this

```
var _materialTypeEntity = await GetInventoryProducts(cpount);
```